# Deleting Files Older than 30 Days with Robocopy

Tags: robocopy

I want to delete files older than 30 days via Robocopy.

```
Robocopy C:\EmptyDir C:\FullDir /mir /MT /R:0 /W:0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete files older than 30 days in `C:\FullDir` (and all subdirectories), then consider using `forfiles` instead:

```
forfiles /p "C:\FullDir" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

(I would recommend first testing that it does what you want it to do, by using `echo` instead of `del`)

Just like `robocopy`, `forfiles` is also part of Windows - so this solution doesn't require you to download any additional software.

Comment: Robocopy comes as part of Windows and has been since 2008. Also worth noting that on older versions, the switches were hyphenated (e.g. "-s").

Comment: @DanAtkinson My comment about the command being part of Windows relates to `forfiles`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that's my point - robocopy also comes as part of Windows. No need to download anything to use it.

Comment: @DanAtkinson Yes I know robocopy comes as part of Windows. At no point in my anwer did I imply otherwise. I specifically called out that `forfiles` is part of Windows so the OP realises that, like `robocopy`, they don't have a download anything.

Comment: @DanAtkinson I have updated the copy to make it even clearer.